# Clear my mind on this js pattern

Tags: javascript

I see often this pattern

```
  (function(){}).call(this)
```

Is that the same with this one?

```
  (function(that){})(this)
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Are those two codes trying to solve the same problem? the context of **this**?

**EDIT**

Can anyone edit the title and provide a better one cause I think it is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after the question**:

No. [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) accepts `this` as its first argument. `this` is not passed into a function as a real argument in this case. However, you can address the actually passed `this` as `that` in the second function.

**EDIT**: Here's an example.

```
MyObject = {};
MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function(value) { console.log("Hello, " + value); }
var obj = new MyObject();

function myMethodCaller(value)
{
    this.myMethod(value);
}

myMethodCaller("World!");
myMethodCaller.call(obj, "World!");
```

- The first call will fail with an error, as [implicitly] `this` (receiver) will most often be the `window` (more generally, the global object, whatever it is in your context. It is different e.g. for workers) which does not have the `myMethod` method.
- The second call will log "Hello, World!" into your console, since `this` will point to `obj`, on which the `myMethod` method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not, the other one gives the function an object context and the other one passes an argument without any object context.

Imagine a generic function, like `Array#shift()`:

```
var shift = Array.prototype.shift;

//Shift expects an object context, and cannot be called without one.


//so this won't work:
shift($("div"))
//undefined

//This does:
shift.call($("div"))
//<div id=​"notify-container">​</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are those two codes trying to solve the same problem? the context of
>   this?

Yes, but in a different manner.

The first version invokes `Function.prototype.call` which as first argument, accepts the context-object to which the `this` variable within the called function-context will refer to.

The second version just self-invokes the anonymous function and passes the object which refers to `this` (in the calling context) to the anonymous function. Now, within the called anonymous function-context, we can access it via `that`. **`this` will be `global` or `undefined` (depends on ES5 strict mode)**